# Computer freezes or display freeze ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, kernel

My computer freezes randomly, Below details I found in kernal logs. If can one can help.

```
May 22 13:10:45 spider systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May 22 13:10:45 spider systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
May 22 13:10:45 spider systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
May 22 13:10:45 spider systemd-sleep[7226]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
May 22 13:10:45 spider kernel: [ 5465.214908] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.218255] Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.218544] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.221450] OOM killer disabled.
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.221450] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.223090] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290386] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290390] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: SMU uninitialized but power gate requested for 6!
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290417] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 123 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../pm/swsmu/amdgpu_smu.c:227 smu_dpm_set_power_gate+0x1d9/0x200 [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290639] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) bridge cmac stp llc algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_acp3x_rn snd_soc_dmic snd_acp3x_pdm_dma snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_hda_intel snd_sof snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_sof_utils intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec amdgpu intel_rapl_common binfmt_misc snd_soc_core snd_hda_core rtw88_8822ce rtw88_8822c snd_hwdep snd_compress snd_seq_midi ac97_bus snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm_dmaengine rtw88_pci joydev snd_pci_ps btusb snd_rawmidi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl edac_mce_amd videobuf2_memops iommu_v2 btbcm snd_acp_pci gpu_sched rtw88_core snd_seq snd_pci_acp6x videobuf2_v4l2 btintel drm_ttm_helper kvm_amd ttm
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290683]  btmtk snd_pcm videobuf2_common snd_seq_device mac80211 kvm drm_display_helper crct10dif_pclmul bluetooth nls_iso8859_1 videodev cec input_leds snd_timer ghash_clmulni_intel mc snd_pci_acp5x rc_core cfg80211 ecdh_generic aesni_intel drm_kms_helper ecc snd crypto_simd snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit cryptd fb_sys_fops hp_wmi snd_acp_config syscopyarea sysfillrect sparse_keymap rapl serio_raw platform_profile snd_soc_acpi hid_multitouch wmi_bmof ccp libarc4 soundcore sysimgblt snd_pci_acp3x k10temp mac_hid wireless_hotkey amd_pmc acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp ramoops parport reed_solomon pstore_blk drm pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme xhci_pci hid_generic crc32_pclmul nvme_core i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid video hid
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290728] CPU: 6 PID: 123 Comm: kworker/6:1 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290730] Hardware name: HP HP Laptop 15-ef2xxx/887A, BIOS F.27 10/20/2022
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290732] Workqueue: events amdgpu_device_delay_enable_gfx_off [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.290855] RIP: 0010:smu_dpm_set_power_gate+0x1d9/0x200 [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291008] Code: e2 4c 8b 6f 50 4d 85 ed 75 03 4c 8b 2f e8 0f 42 9e c8 41 89 d8 4c 89 e1 4c 89 ea 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 00 ed 2b c2 e8 97 36 ec c8 <0f> 0b b8 a1 ff ff ff e9 bf fe ff ff e9 c9 6d 38 00 e9 c4 6d 38 00
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291009] RSP: 0018:ffffaa67c0607dd0 EFLAGS: 00010246
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291011] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000006 RCX: 0000000000000000
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291012] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291012] RBP: ffffaa67c0607df8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291013] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc230d674
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291014] R13: ffff9ed5813dd8b0 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff9ed598cc8be8
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291015] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9ed98a780000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291016] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291017] CR2: 00007f84632965b0 CR3: 0000000162c10000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291018] Call Trace:
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291020]  <TASK>
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291023]  amdgpu_dpm_set_powergating_by_smu+0xa4/0x180 [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291190]  amdgpu_device_delay_enable_gfx_off+0x46/0x70 [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291312]  process_one_work+0x21f/0x400
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291317]  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291318]  ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291320]  kthread+0xee/0x120
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291321]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291323]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291327]  </TASK>
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.291328] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [ 5465.622612] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10886.751591] amd_pmc AMDI0005:00: Last suspend didn't reach deepest state
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10886.791589] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10887.331320] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10887.331330] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10887.401879] nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10887.408138] nvme nvme0: Ignoring bogus Namespace Identifiers
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10887.662607] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10907.333679] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to write reg 28b4 wait reg 28c6
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10927.332939] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to write reg 1a6f4 wait reg 1a706
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10947.335961] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to write reg 28b4 wait reg 28c6
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10967.338758] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: failed to write reg 1a6f4 wait reg 1a706
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634370] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 26s! [kworker/u32:19:6799]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634377] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp nft_compat nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) bridge cmac stp llc algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_acp3x_rn snd_soc_dmic snd_acp3x_pdm_dma snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_hda_intel snd_sof snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_sof_utils intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec amdgpu intel_rapl_common binfmt_misc snd_soc_core snd_hda_core rtw88_8822ce rtw88_8822c snd_hwdep snd_compress snd_seq_midi ac97_bus snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm_dmaengine rtw88_pci joydev snd_pci_ps btusb snd_rawmidi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl edac_mce_amd videobuf2_memops iommu_v2 btbcm snd_acp_pci gpu_sched rtw88_core snd_seq snd_pci_acp6x videobuf2_v4l2 btintel drm_ttm_helper kvm_amd ttm
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634480]  btmtk snd_pcm videobuf2_common snd_seq_device mac80211 kvm drm_display_helper crct10dif_pclmul bluetooth nls_iso8859_1 videodev cec input_leds snd_timer ghash_clmulni_intel mc snd_pci_acp5x rc_core cfg80211 ecdh_generic aesni_intel drm_kms_helper ecc snd crypto_simd snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit cryptd fb_sys_fops hp_wmi snd_acp_config syscopyarea sysfillrect sparse_keymap rapl serio_raw platform_profile snd_soc_acpi hid_multitouch wmi_bmof ccp libarc4 soundcore sysimgblt snd_pci_acp3x k10temp mac_hid wireless_hotkey amd_pmc acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp ramoops parport reed_solomon pstore_blk drm pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme xhci_pci hid_generic crc32_pclmul nvme_core i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid video hid
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634569] CPU: 0 PID: 6799 Comm: kworker/u32:19 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634574] Hardware name: HP HP Laptop 15-ef2xxx/887A, BIOS F.27 10/20/2022
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634578] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.634592] RIP: 0010:gfxhub_v1_0_program_invalidation+0xbf/0x170 [amdgpu]
May 22 14:43:05 spider kernel: [10991.635099] Code: 37 14 51 00 48 8b 83 40 74 01 00 41 83 e5 01 8b 93 74 50 00 00 8b 08 75 73 8b 10 8b 83 74 50 00 00 31 c9 48 89 df 41 0f af c4 <41> 83 c4 01 8d b4 02 c8 08 00 00 ba 1f 00 00 00 e8 dc c6 f5 ff 41
```